# Infinite-time Turing machines and the formal Church's thesis

Tags: lo.logic, constructive-mathematics, intuitionism, infinite-time-computability

Infinite-time Turing machines are known to either halt or loop in countable time.

In the spirit of double-negation translation, is there a statement which is: classically equivalent to this; consistent with the formal Church's thesis, that all total functions on the integers are recursive; and (this part is of course subjective) which actually tells us something "meaningful or informative" beyond the vacuous sense in which any such translation does?

Comment: "Church's thesis" usually means something like "all effectively computable functions are Turing computable". You seem to be referring to the *formal* Church's thesis, which is part of Russian constructivism. I think you should make that clear. Next, if you assume that all functions are computable, then how do you define the countable ordinals and infinite-time Turing machines? You don't have excluded middle anymore and you need to be careful.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My understanding had been that the informal statement was distinguished by the name "Church-Turing thesis"; I've edited the wording as you suggested. Regarding your second point, I suppose my question can be interpreted as asking the same thing in a specific way. In other words, is it still possible for a constructivist to derive meaningful conclusions from some version of the classical result, even without committing to every (ordinary) Turing machine either halting or not?

Comment: The problem is not that constructively we do not have "every machine halts or not". The problem you are facing is that (at least to me) it is not at all clear how to define infinite-time Turing machines constructively. The reason for this is that it is not clear how to define ordinal numbers constructively.

Comment: I think I was hoping that there might be intuitionistically valid statement(s) which are classically equivalent to the one saying infinite-time Turing machines halt or loop in countable time, but which do not themselves explicitly refer to such machines.

Comment: I’ll try again: you can’t even say “infinite time Turing machine” or anything like it, so you don’t get a chance at reformulating the statement. I thought about this and couldn’t see it. If anyone knows please let me know.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. I was imagining a statement which was not a direct syntactic translation, but was still classically equivalent (as in Reverse Mathematics), but just realized that any such statement would still have to imply some statement about ordinals which would not be expressible constructively.

Comment: Right. For instance, in the effective topos we have the object of countable ordinals, but it's not very nice (it's just $\nabla \omega_1$ so it has trivial computability structure). We also have the object of recursive countable ordinals, which is essentially $\omega_1^{CK}$ with a standard numbering. But I don't think we want ot use $\omega_1^{CK}$ to formulate infnite-time Turing machines, or do we? The problem you need to overcome is: what happens at a limit stage? The $\lim\sup$ of a sequence of decidable truth values ($0$ and $1$) need not be decidable. So what will the Turing machine do?